# VirtualBox not running: Kernel driver not installed since recent update to 6.1.0 kernel (Ubuntu 22.04.2)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 22.04

I was using VirtualBox (installed from Ubuntu repositories) on the day right before I installed the most recent upgrade for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS which installed Linux kernel 6.1.0-1015, previous kernel was 5.15.0-76. Since then I can not start VirtualBox. What can I do? It shows this error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
> correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the
> kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
> the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
> you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
> more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
> support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

The recommended solution fails:

When trying to reinstall virtualbox-dkms, I can see the problem here:

```
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.38 DKMS files...
Building for 6.1.0-1015-oem
Module build for kernel 6.1.0-1015-oem was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

Jul 03 20:12:15 Abook systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Jul 03 20:12:15 Abook virtualbox[11380]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Jul 03 20:12:15 Abook virtualbox[11380]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1476137/65362), regarding a similar problem with Nvidia drivers not working after kernel update:

```
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

And reboot, now it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

For ref in case anyone else looking for a solution, I don't have nvidia drivers but running

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

installed what was needed and then (again)

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb
```

worked for me on 22.04.