# nvidia drivers installed but don't work after update

Tags: nvidia, updates, cuda

I saw some other answers about nvidia drivers after update (`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`). But my nvidia installation doesn't work anymore

For example:

- my second monitor which is connected by usb-C adapter doesn't work anymore
- `nvidia-smi` returns me

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

- and I can't use CUDA anymore

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

I tried some answers so I did `prime-select query` then `prime-select on-demand` cause on-demand was the only option I had.

But my drivers are installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep "nvidia-"
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-530:amd64                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-cfg1-535
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-530                       535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              all          Transitional package for libnvidia-common-535
ii  libnvidia-common-535                       535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
iU  libnvidia-compute-530:amd64                535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-compute-535
iU  libnvidia-compute-530:i386                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         Transitional package for libnvidia-compute-535
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
iU  libnvidia-decode-530:amd64                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-decode-535
iU  libnvidia-decode-530:i386                  535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         Transitional package for libnvidia-decode-535
iU  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
iU  libnvidia-decode-535:i386                  535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
iU  libnvidia-encode-530:amd64                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-encode-535
iU  libnvidia-encode-530:i386                  535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         Transitional package for libnvidia-encode-535
iU  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                 535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
iU  libnvidia-encode-535:i386                  535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
iU  libnvidia-extra-530:amd64                  535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-extra-535
ii  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                  535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-530:amd64                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-fbc1-535
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-530:i386                    535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         Transitional package for libnvidia-fbc1-535
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386                    535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-530:amd64                     535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-gl-535
ii  libnvidia-gl-530:i386                      535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         Transitional package for libnvidia-gl-535
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                     535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:i386                      535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
iU  nvidia-compute-utils-530:amd64             535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-compute-utils-535
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-535                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
iU  nvidia-dkms-530                            535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-dkms-535
iF  nvidia-dkms-535                            535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
iU  nvidia-driver-530                          535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-535
iU  nvidia-driver-535                          535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-535-535.54.03              535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-530:amd64             535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-kernel-common-535
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-535                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-530                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-kernel-source-535
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-535                   535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.17.1                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            510.47.03-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
iU  nvidia-utils-530:amd64                     535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-utils-535
ii  nvidia-utils-535                           535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18.2                                  all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
iU  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-530:amd64        535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Transitional package for xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535
iU  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535              535.54.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

So I have the right driver (?) with `nvidia-driver-535` because ubuntu says me it's one for my GPU running `ubuntu-drivers devices`

Also I already had an issue with my external monitor and I had to config ubuntu to use integrated gpu (amd) for desktop apps and use my nvidia GPU only for CUDA

How to fix my actual issue to get back this behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

I just found my answer:

```
sudo dkms autoinstall
```

In my case it worked